# derived value in a python map

Tags: python, function, dictionary

question i am not sure is possible but asking anyways, lets say i have some dictionary:

```
 my_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1}
```

i would like to have some key 'c' be equal to (in this simple case) values a+b so that if i were to update the dictionary:

```
my_dict['a'] = 2
```

then calling:

```
my_dict['c']
```

would return 3 (a=2 + b=1)

I wasn't able to find any easy way, maybe a lambda function, but that didn't seem right.  This would be useful whenever I would want the sum of a & b i wouldn't have to explicitly pull them out and add them.

EDIT:  thanks for the quick responses, this would work with a class, if i always knew that value C i wanted to perform some function, but i'd like to be able to dynamically define the function, lets say in my_dict i wanted 'c' to be a+b but in some other my_dict_2 i wanted key 'b' to be (key='a' * 52)/3 (or some other basic mathematical operation.  In the below solutions, I'd have to keep re-writing classes, and I would prefer not to.  Any thoughts ?

Comment: I've added more 'generic' solution, hope you'll like it.

Comment: Note that Łukasz R.'s latest solution is very flexible: you can add new functions to an existing instance at any time, and the `lambda` function associated to a key in `defaults` can access any of the values in the dict, both the normal ones & the special ones in `defaults`, so it can get as complex as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical problem to solve by implementing a simple class.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b


o = MyClass()
o.a = 1
o.b = 2
assert o.c == 3
o.a = 2
assert o.c == 4
```

If you has to be a dict you may create custom class and override `__getitem__` magic method.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'c':
            return self['a'] + self['b']
        return super(MyDict, self).__getitem__(key)


my_dict = MyDict()
my_dict['a'] = 1
my_dict['b'] = 2
assert my_dict['c'] == 3
my_dict['b'] = 3
assert my_dict['c'] == 4
assert isinstance(my_dict, dict)
```

If you want to have generic solution I'll go with something like this:

```
class DefaultDict(dict):
    defaults = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.defaults:
            return self.defaults[key](self)
        return super(DefaultDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.defaults:
            raise RuntimeError('Default key: %s' % key)
        super(DefaultDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)


# alt. 1
o1 = DefaultDict()
o1.defaults = {'c': lambda d: d['a'] + d['b']}
o1['a'] = 1
o1['b'] = 2
assert o1['c'] == 3


# alt. 2
class DefaultDict1(DefaultDict):
    defaults = {'c': lambda d: d['a'] + d['b']}


o2 = DefaultDict1()
o2['a'] = 1
o2['b'] = 2
assert o2['c'] == 3
```

Comment: Nice work. Although I'd probably use a different name for the class to avoid confusing it with [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `dict` and override `__getitem__` magic function:

```
class SumDict(dict):
    SUM_KEY = 'c'

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == self.SUM_KEY:
            return sum(self.values())
        return super(SumDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key == self.SUM_KEY:
            raise KeyError('{} key is reserved'.format(key))
        super(SumDict, self).__setitem__(key, val)
```

--

```
>>> d = SumDict({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3})
>>> print(d['c'])
6

>>> d['c'] = 10
KeyError: 'c key is reserved'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a plain `dict`, but you can do something like it with a class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b    

t = MyClass(2, 3)
print t.c
t.a = 10
print t.c
t.b = 5
print t.c
```

**output**

```
5
13
15
```